# Query based on Count, Time frame, and location

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok so I need to write a query that I am probably making much more complicated than it needs to be but I could use some help.

I need to select records of clients that have not been seen for a year or longer, have seen us more than once but can be only once if it is not at certain locations.

So what I have so far is:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 
    client_id,
    location_id, 
    employee_id,
    create_timestamp, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC) AS ROW
FROM
    client_Appointment 
)

SELECT 
    c.client_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    CTE AS ce
    INNER JOIN person  AS c
        ON p.person_id= ce.client_id
    INNER JOIN employee_mstr AS em
        ON em.employee_id = ce.empoyee_id
    INNER JOIN location_mstr AS lm
        ON lm.location_id = ce.location_id
WHERE
   ce.create_timestamp <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE()), 120)
GROUP BY
    p.person_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

I'm unsure where to go from here. Also this does not get me all the info I need and if I add that information to the select clause I have to use it in group by which means I don't get all the needed records.
Thanks

Comment: Please add sample data as well as current and expected output.

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want only clients who have not been seen in a year or more,
then clients that have either one visit NOT at certain locations OR more than one visit. Did I get that right?

Note: Just replace (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) with your table name

```
WITH CTE_visits
AS
(
SELECT 
    c.client_id,
    COUNT(*) AS total_visits,
    SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN ce.location_id IN (SELECT ID FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) AS A(ID)) THEN 0 --so when it is a certain location then do NOT count it
                ELSE 1 --if it is not at the certain locations, then count it
            END
        ) AS visits_not_at_certain_locations
FROM
    client_Appointment AS ce
    INNER JOIN person  AS c
        ON p.person_id= ce.client_id
    INNER JOIN employee_mstr AS em
        ON em.employee_id = ce.empoyee_id
    INNER JOIN location_mstr AS lm
        ON lm.location_id = ce.location_id
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT client_id, MAX(create_timestamp) last_visit FROM client_Appointment WHERE client_id = ce.client_id GROUP BY client_id) CA --find most recent visit for each client_id
WHERE
    ce.create_timestamp <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE()), 120) --remember this only counts visits over a year ago
    AND last_visit <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE()), 120) --says only return client_id's who's last visit is more than a year ago
GROUP BY
    p.person_id
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_visits
WHERE   visits_not_at_certain_locations = 1 --seen once NOT at certain locations
        OR total_visits > 1 --seen more than once at any location
```